# Would "Final Embrace Master" work for a dragon character and could it combo with "Vital strike"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

A little context for my character, I am currently playing a kobold Sorcerer with the Gold Dragon, Efreeti, and Phoenix bloodlines and my DM gave be the Gold Dragon Mythic path from Wrath of the Righteous reflavored into a crystal dragon so I have 3 dragon feats that allow me to take any feat without any of the prerequisites and I was planning on taking "Final Embrace Master" for my second one and I have a few questions on how it would play into my build.

The first question I have is weather or not a constrict attack is even possible for a dragon considering this feat is meant for a Naga and considering Nagas are almost all tail would my character even be able to perform a constrict attack?

The second question is: would I still be able to make attacks if I am constricting someone because the rules for grappling someone are somewhat vague to me and everywhere I look it doesn't  say that I can or can't make additional attacks to targets I am grappling.

And the final question is if and how this would combo with Vital Strike? From what I can see Vital Strike can be used with any attack that isn't a spell attack so could I Vital Strike a Constrict attack, and if I can, would the vital strike damage apply to each round of constrict damage, or only the first turn, or would I have to keep activating Vital Strike each round for it to apply?

Answer (score 7):

### 1.

[Constrict](https://aonprd.com/UMR.aspx?ItemName=Constrict) is an ability that some monsters have, it's not a special attack anyone can make. i.e. If we look at the statblock of a [Viper Vine](https://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Viper%20Vine) we can see that under it's special attacks it has listed:

> constrict (1d6+8)

So if your character has the constrict ability while in dragon form (which gold dragons normally don't have), they would be able to use as per normal.

### 2.

You can attack while grappling, there's nothing preventing you from doing so.

However, [grapples](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Grapple&Category=Combat%20Maneuvers) have some [rules](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Conditions&Category=Combat) associated with them:

- You have a -4 penalty to Dex.
- You cannot use more than 1 hand for actions.
- You take a -2 penalty to all attack and combat maneuver rolls
- It's a standard action to maintain a grapple by default, which is the same action needed to make a single attack, and in order to make more than 1 attack you have to take a full-round action.

So while, yes, you can attack, it's also kind of bad to do so.

### 3.

Constrict doesn't work [Vital Strike](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Vital%20Strike) at all.

> When you use the attack action

Vital strike only works with attack action, constrict occurs when you make a grapple check which is different.